# Do the included apps of different Office 2010 versions have the same features?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I can vaguely recall that back in the time of Office XP/2003 there was a difference in features individual Office programs had.

For instance, I believe Excel didn't have XML export features in basic editions, but had them in Professional edition.

Is that not true anymore for Office 2010?

[The comparison chart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/office-2010-which-suite-is-right-for-you-FX101825640.aspx) only tells whether a program is included or not. I couldn't find a more detailed chart on MS website.

Am I safe to assume that if a program is included in an edition, then it will have all features, as if it came from the Professional edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no limitations in certain editions of the Microsoft Office 2010 package (except for the Starter edition, which is severely limited).

The main difference, as you already realized yourself, is what products are included in the package.

In case you want to be absolutely sure about what is contained in a specific product, you can check the [Office 2010 Product Guides](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5829) or simply download a [free trial version](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/redir/XT101937428.aspx).

Comment: Hmm... The product guide says you need Professional for publishing to the web services. On the other hand, the guide portrays the looks and not the wits. Things like XML export, database connectivity and VBA are not even mentioned. I think I will try a trial.